# passing variable to another function

Tags: matlab, function, variables

How do I pass a variable `A` from `browseBtn_Callback` function to `runBtn_Callback` function? I need to click on run button to generate the result, but the example code below will automatically produce the result without the button click:

```
function browseBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
A = load('new2.txt');
runBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles, A);


function runBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles, A)
B = get(handles.edit1, 'String');
compare = strcmp(A,B);
if(compare == 1)
  set(handles.result, 'String', 'Correct', 'ForegroundColor', 'green');
else
  set(handles.result, 'String', 'Incorrect', 'ForegroundColor', 'red');
end
```

Comment: Which variable are you trying to pass between functions? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to pass 'A' from browseBtn_Callback to runBtn_Callback

Answer (score 1):

Use the `handles` argument to store `A` as a property of the figure. Read about this option, and others, here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html

The other thing you need to do is not call `runBtn_Callback` directly from within `browseBtn_Callback` - that is why it is running immediately. Get rid of that line, and then the function will only be executed when you click the button.

```
function browseBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.A = load('new2.txt');



function runBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
B = get(handles.edit1, 'String');
compare = strcmp(handles.A,B);
if(compare == 1)
  set(handles.result, 'String', 'Correct', 'ForegroundColor', 'green');
else
  set(handles.result, 'String', 'Incorrect', 'ForegroundColor', 'red');
end
```